# Libreoffice Writer (headless and non headless) remove signature of pdf after exporting it to PDF/A

Tags: pdf, pdfa, libreoffice-writer

I am exporting a signed PDF to PDF/A with Libreoffice Writer. When I do this, the file is converted to a PDF/A but removes the signature. This happens in the headless aswell as in the GUI.

The PDF was signed with the [Portable Signer2](https://github.com/pflaeging/PortableSigner2)

Comment: By *signature* you mean a digital signature? Or just some image of an ink signature? In the former case: Converting PDF to PDF/A considerably changes the PDF internally, so if the signature was left in the PDF, it would become invalid in the course of the conversion...

Comment: @mkl I see, so I'll have to find another way. Could you post your comment as an aswer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting PDF to PDF/A considerably changes the PDF internally, so if the (digital) signature was left in the PDF, it would become invalid in the course of the conversion.